# Switch user boot shortcut 16.04

Tags: boot, login, shortcut-keys

On my grandma's pc, i have set up, that ubuntu boots right into her account (without the greeter). When I want to use my account (to install updates or apps, just change some settings - basicly sudo stuff), I need to wait for cinnamon to load and then i log out, to the greeter and back to my account. Is there a way, of setting up a keyboard shortcut, that when held at certain time during boot will make the pc load the greeter or my account?

Comment: Is this similar to what you want?

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible with any of the display managers available in Ubuntu.

Comment: @M.Becerra What?